# Flutter StreamBuilder with type as superclass

Tags: dart, flutter

Maybe I have structured things wrong so any advice would be appreciated.

Here are my classes:

```
class MainClass {
  final String title;
  MainClass({this.title});
}

class SubClass1 extends MainClass {
  final String subClass1Info;
  SubClass1({this.subClass1Info});
}

class SubClass2 extends MainClass {
  final String subClass2Info;
  SubClass2({this.subClass2Info});
}

class SubClass3 extends MainClass {
  final String subClass3Info;
  SubClass3({this.subClass3Info});
}
```

Then I have a StreamBuilder:

```
StreamBuilder<MainClass>(
          stream: _bloc.stream,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<MainClass> snapshot) {

});
```

Either SubClass1, SubClass2 or SubClass3 can be sent through the stream and the child Widgets will need to know which type they are dealing with.

How do I best achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `is` keyword to check if an object is any of your `Classes`

```
                        StreamBuilder<MainClass>(
                  stream: null,
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<MainClass> snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      if (snapshot.data is SubClass1) {
                        final SubClass1 myData = snapshot.data as SubClass1;
                        return Container(
                          child: Text("SubClass1"),
                        );
                      } else if (snapshot.data is SubClass2) {
                        final SubClass2 myData = snapshot.data as SubClass2;
                        return Container(
                          child: Text("SubClass2"),
                        );
                      } else if (snapshot.data is SubClass3) {
                        final SubClass3 myData = snapshot.data as SubClass3;
                        return Container(
                          child: Text("SubClass3"),
                        );
                      }
                    } else {
                      return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    }
                  })
```

Comment: What if the widget tree was much deeper than just Container(child: Text()) and you need to set the type of snapshot.data to what the subclass is?

Comment: It was just a sample, you can use any widget according the type of your object

Comment: Ok, but each subclass shares most of same widgets, this method would result in repeating a lot of code

Comment: Extract the widget and create your own StatelessWidget and you can pass any data

Comment: How can I access the subclass data for example subClass3Info? Your example still assumes the type is MainClass for snapshot.data